# How a Google cloud compute instance (with oslogin enabled) integrates with "/etc/passwd", "/etc/group", etc?

Tags: debian, gcloud, user-management

How a Google cloud compute instance (with oslogin enabled) integrates with "/etc/passwd", "/etc/group", etc?

My default username/group isn't listed on the /etc/passwd and /etc/group and it works (ls -l resolve the user/group names correctly). Where this information come from?

Does local (inside the vm, not intended for ssh) user/group management could follow the traditional way (addgroup / adduser / usermod) without problem?

How can I add my default (oslogin) user to a group defined in /etc/group ?

Edit 1: How can I add an ordinary user (from /etc/passw) to a group defined by oslogin?

Note: I'm using the default image "debian buster".

Comment: See: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/guest-oslogin

Comment: How can I add an ordinary user (from /etc/passw) to a group defined by oslogin?

Comment: Question updated using the comment above.

Comment: Only users credentials that are part of the project's users (with suitable IAM roles) are able to access VMs with OS Login enabled. See: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#configure_users

Comment: @DazWilkin, May be I've not been clear.  I understand that the VM access (by ssh) are restricted to those IAM credentials. What I wanted to ask was: How can I add an ordinary user (from /etc/passw) to a group G defined by oslogin to have access to files/directories that have G as their group ownership (not related to VM access)?